# How to create Excel file from List<string> using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, excel-interop

I've a List with some values, I've also a TextBox where I must write a number, then I need to build a Excel with many Sheets with values coming from List. In other words and for example: List have 1000 values, then I enter 100 in TextBox, so I'll need to generate a Excel file with many sheets as values are in List iterating over the value entered in the TextBox in this case will be one Excel file with 10 sheets, every sheet with 100 cells. It's clear? How I can do this using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Comment: OK, can you show us what you've tried? Looks like you have a pretty clear description of the problem, did you expect us to write it for you?

Comment: @tnw no, I just want to get some ideas because I know the code for write one cell but not for write many cells and create sheets, that's what I'm ask

Comment: @tnw also I'm reading [this](http://www.4microsoftsolutions.com/post/Create-Excel-file-Open-Excel-file-Write-and-Read-Excel-file-in-C.aspx) but is not clear for me at all, I'm not a C# expert, these are my first steps

Comment: Show us what you've tried here and we'll go from there.

Comment: @tnw I don't try nothing yet, I'm just reading and trying to understand how to get this done

Comment: Here on SO, you typically won't get any answers until there's been an appropriate amount of effort on your side. That means research, a reasonable and demonstrable attempt at the problem, and additionally constructing a well thought out question **with code examples** where you're running into **specific** problems. I don't mean to be rude, but going through these steps before asking a question is absolutely expected of programmers of all skill levels.

Answer (score 0):

For worksheets:

```
//get the first workbook in an application
Workbook WB = Application.Workbooks[0]; //Or any other workbook you preffer

Now loop the following for each list of strings you have (each list to a worksheet)
    Worksheet WS = (Worksheet)WB.Worksheets.Add(); //this command adds worksheets
    Range R = WS.Range["A1"];  //or any other cell you like

    //now for cells
    for (int i = 0; i < YourStringList.Count; i++) //I believe you can manage to separate the lists yourself
    {
        R.Offset[i, 0].Value = YourStringList[i];
    }
End of the loop
```

Comment: I've a doubt regarding this, this code will create a workbook with one worksheet right? This is created on the fly? How I can save this file in order to get a Excel file? should I add a saveDialog component in order to save the file? I'm a bit lost here

Comment: The Workbook represents a file. The code is Getting with `Workbooks[0]` the first workbook in excel application. You can add workbooks as well with `Workbooks.Add`. A Workbook has the "save" methods with some options (you can use dialogs if you like). And yes, I gave you code to create single sheet, but you can create as many as you like inside a single Workbook. You can use the `Worksheets.Add` in a loop to create as many as the number of lists you have. (corrected a mistake in code, please check it)

Comment: Hmm, I get lost with your edit! If you read my first question I say I'll have 10 sheets based on `YourStringList.Count/TextBox1.Text` this is what you say here?